# how to have a column count the number of times a BIT field is zero and another column counting the number of time it is one?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PartsWork](
    [parts_work_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [experiment_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [partition_id] [int] NULL,
    [part_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [sim_time] [int] NULL,
    [real_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [construction] [bit] NULL,
    [destruction] [bit] NULL,
    [duration] [int] NULL )
```

I want to write a SQL that outputs the `part_id`, number of times `construction` is = 1 and number of times `destruction` is = 1 for a given `experiment_id` AND `partition_id`.

I can do this using multi-statement table valued functions and a loop, but I would like to be able to do this in a single SQL. Is this possible?

Comment: How many part_id values do you expect for a given experiment_id AND partition_id?

Comment: I expect to get about 4 part_id's for each partition_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give all part_id values, you need the OVER clause on the COUNT (this is an inline aggregation without using GROUP BY)

```
SELECT
    part_id,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN construction = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER () AS CountConstructionIs1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN destruction = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER () AS CountDestructionIs1
FROM
   [dbo].[PartsWork]
WHERE
    experiment_id = @experiment_id
    AND
    partition_id = @partition_id
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) for more